# Is it possible to run specific test case ([TestMethod]) from code using TestCategory or any other attributes?

Tags: c#, selenium, mstest

I know we can run specific TestMethods using Test Filter Criteria from TFS and console.  I am looking for a way to execute specific TestMethod from code as mentioned in [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vikramagrawal/2012/04/26/testcasefilter-in-vs11-unit-testing-beta/)

Using Client API

```
TestRunCriteria runCriteria = CreateTestRunCriteria(); 
runCriteria.TestCaseFilter = “TestCategory=Nightly”;
```

Is this possible? or is there any other way to execute the TestMethods from code.
And I am using MSTest not NUnit or XUnit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that using `TestCategory`

Example :-

```
[TestCategory("Nightly"), TestCategory("Weekly"), TestCategory("ShoppingCart"), TestMethod()]  
public void DebitTest()  
{  
}
```

Above code have many TestCategory and it can run as per the grouping of msTest

```
/testcontainer:"D:\NET_Workspace\automation\API.Test\TestMasterData\bin\Debug\API.Test.TestMasterData.dll" /category:Nightly /resultsfile:D:\Testcases_Reports\TestResult.trx
```

Now above command only run `Nightly` test group for you

From visual studio follow below steps :-

```
In your Test Explorer, right click and select "Group by -> Traits".
```

I have found one documentation for it too.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I have mentioned it in the question itself, It can be run from console and TFS.  What about from code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Name= <TestMethodDisplayNameName>` condition. Related article: [Running selective unit tests in VS 2012 using TestCaseFilter](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charles_sterling/2012/09/26/running-selective-unit-tests-in-vs-2012-using-testcasefilter/).

Comment: Trying the related article codes give all errors, it required some base classes ??

Comment: @vince You can call MSTest.exe or VSTest.Console.exe programming. Check this code: https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/blob/master/samples/Microsoft.TestPlatform.TranslationLayer.E2ETest/Program.cs